# Using ClaimsTransformer to set user permissions creates lengthy cookies and rejected by browsers

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

In our Aspnet core 1.1 app, we are using ClaimsTransformer to set permissions for the current user at the start of each request. It appears the cookie got bigger due to this and sometimes I see a warning in browser's console that the cookie was rejected as it was too long. Is it possible to add claims to identity without being passed down to the client through cookies? If not, is it possible to replace the cookie value with a Guid or some identifier and retain the lengthy cookie in the server itself or possibly DB?

This is how our code looks like

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformer
{
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
    {
        var principal = context.Principal;
        if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return principal;

        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

        var db = context.Context.RequestServices.GetService<IDb>();
        var entity = await db.Entity.FirstAsync(/*Add conditions here*/);

        //This list is expected to grow with time.
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("CanManageAPIs", entity.CanManageAPIs.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("CanManageUsers", entity.CanManageUsers.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("CanManageSystems", entity.CanManageSystems.ToString()));

        return principal;
    }
}

    //Configure method in Startup.cs
    app.UseClaimsTransformation(new ClaimsTransformationOptions
    {
        Transformer = new ClaimsTransformer()
    });

public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static bool CanManageSystems(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var value = principal.GetClaimValue("CanManageSystems");
        bool.TryParse(value, out bool result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And use the claims in our views.

```
@if (User.CanManageSystems())
{
    <!-- Render some HTML content here. -->
}
```

**Update Sep 03**

I am not able to reproduce the issue anymore with the same source code without any local changes. The length of the cookie with name .AspNetCore.Cookies remains constant at 3331 irrespective of the number of claims being added to the identity and they are not persisting either. I did see that earlier when I was able to reproduce the issue, there two more cookies with names .AspNetCore.Cookies1 and .AspNetCore.Cookies2. The only change that happened between then and now is a claim was removed by one of my colleagues in Azure AD B2C and I can't say for sure if that is the reason. Since I don't have access to that part of Azure, I will need to wait for him to get back to work on Tuesday ET to do some experimenting.

**Update Sep 11**

I was able to get back to this issue today and figured out what caused the problem. As I keep browsing through the pages, when I cross half way mark of cookie expiration (approx. 3mins out of 5mins I configured to test), a new cookie is issued. And this cookie includes all the claims that were added by ClaimsTransformer code above and persists across page requests. The claims added during the subsequent requests seem to not overwrite but instead add additional claims to the identity. So I updated my code to remove existing claim if detected and add new one instead. This solves my problem.

However I would like to know if this is the expected behavior and I am using the claims incorrectly. Or is it a bug that I stumbled upon?

Comment: What kind of data inside CanManageAPIs, CanManageUsers and CanManageSystems? It should not be an issue if they are boolean value. You can look at my [code](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web.Common/Security/SignInManager.cs#L20).

Comment: You should check the content of all Claims inside your identity, there may be others which increase the size of the cookie.

Comment: @Win Yes they are boolean fields for now. My code and yours are similar except that I am using OpenIdConnect.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I added an update to my original post.

Comment: I do not believe the cookie will be overwritten if you do not logout the user (or delete it from the browser). Also claim transformation happens server-side, so do not expect that any claim you add inside that method will be persisted inside the cookie.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I have added new information to the post. Can you please review?